# Updating of labels in viewDidLoad is not happening?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, delegates

I'm creating an iOS application that is dealing with Salesforce SDK.

To send requests(here I'm sending 3 requests), I wrote the code in `viewDidLoad()`.

I'm getting the response in

```
func request(request: SFRestRequest, didLoadResponse jsonResponse: AnyObject)
```

I'm trying to update the labels in `viewDidLoad()` but it is not happening.
Please help me?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("SELECT name,active__c,createdbyid,phone,fax,LastActivityDate,lastmodifiedbyid from account where id='"+tempAccId+"'");//This is my first request to fetch some data
        SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(request, delegate: self);
        let requestForCreatedBy = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("select name from user where id in (SELECT createdbyId from account where id='\(tempAccId)')");//second request fetch createdby
        SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(requestForCreatedBy, delegate: self);
        let requestForlastmodifiedBy = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("select name from user where id in (SELECT lastmodifiedbyid from account where id='\(tempAccId)')");//third request to fetch modified by
        SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(requestForlastmodifiedBy, delegate: self);
        //To draw a line under the tittle
        let path:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 145))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 145))

        let shapeLAyer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLAyer.path = path.CGPath
        shapeLAyer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor
        shapeLAyer.lineWidth = 2.0
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLAyer)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        self.AccountTittle.text = name
        self.accountName.text = name
        self.isActive.text = active
        self.lastActivityDate.text = lastActiv
        self.phone.text = phonevar
        self.fax.text = faxvar
        self.createdBy.text = createdByName
        print(createdByName)
        self.lastModifiedBy.text = modifiedByname
        print(createdByName)

    }
```

Comment: where is your code for updating the label ? share your complete code

Comment: Yes, please show some code, but it is likely that your requests are completing asynchronously and you are trying to update the label before the request has completed

Comment: Try in viewDidAppear() instead!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with  viewDidAppear() also.
Before we are getting the response from salesforce viewDidAppear() is getting executed. So some of the labels are not updating.

Comment: Yes, as @Paulw11 said you are trying to updating label because request has completed. Update label after successfully execution of request.

Comment: You have to update the UI in the delegate method (`request:didLoadResponse`). The request object is also be passed to be able to distinguish the requests.

Comment: But how do i distinguish the requests @vadian
Please Explain with code.

Comment: I don't know the API but the request passed in the delegate method is the request you created in `viewDidLoad`. You might retrieve the `query` or other suitable properties to identify the particular request.

Comment: RestApi we are using.

Comment: I have no idea what RestApi is but read the documentation of `SFRestRequest` to figure out which properties are fitting to identify the different requests. Alternatively use properties (instance variables) in your class for the request references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in many comments, your UI updates come before you have terminated your asynchronous request calls. So, you can modify your

```
SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(<requestVar>, delegate: self)
```

with something like:

```
SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(<requestVar>, delegate: self, { (success) -> Void in

    // When request completes,control flow goes here.
    if success {
        // request success
        // update my labels
    } else {
        // request fail
    }
})
```

So , you can transform your function like this:

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (success:Bool) -> Void

func send(<requestVar>, delegate: self, completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {

    // request code.

    let flag = true // true if request succeed,false otherwise

    completionHandler(success: flag)
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Use:

```
SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(request, failBlock: {error in print(error)}, completeBlock: { response in 
     print(response) 
     // update labels
})
```

**EDIT**: About your UI updates:

You create too more shapeLAyer..

declare your shapeLAyer as a class var:

```
var shapeLAyer:CAShapeLayer!

let path:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 145))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 145))

self.shaperLAyer?.removeFromSuperlayer() //remove it if it's exist yet
self.shapeLAyer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLAyer.path = path.CGPath
shapeLAyer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor
shapeLAyer.lineWidth = 2.0
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLAyer)
```

Be sure your UI code running on the main thread, you can write your UI inside the

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
   // update your UI in the main thread 
})
```

I don't know the functions createdByName and modifiedByname, if you post also them (full code) i'll try to help with it..

Comment: 'func send(<requestVar>, delegate: self)'  is actually a api method.
I dont think we can override that.

Comment: Yes, Like you said there is a method as follows.
'SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(request, failBlock: <#T##SFRestFailBlock!##SFRestFailBlock!##(NSError!) -> Void#>, completeBlock: <#T##SFRestResponseBlock!##SFRestResponseBlock!##(AnyObject!) -> Void#>)'
Please help me where to write the UI updation code.

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro Ornano
Idea is working fine. but UI updating a little bit slowly. If U have any idea Share It. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hey @Alessandro Ornano
It is actually taking More Than 15 seconds. Please help me in optimising.

Comment: Thanks boss. Working fine now. Updation of UI is also fast.

Answer (score 1):

From your code what I found understand is, you are initiating the request and immediately setting label texts with some variables, this will not work. I think you are setting the variables in the delegate method, which is triggering after you seeing label texts, so try to update UI in the func `request(request: SFRestRequest, didLoadResponse jsonResponse: AnyObject)` method itself

**Update**
I am not familiar with salesforce sdk, what I could understand is if we are using delegate methods we can't distinguish that for which request the method is calling, so its better to use block based functions if we are creating and calling multiple requests in same class.
For that you can use

```
let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("SELECT name,active__c,createdbyid,phone,fax,LastActivityDate,lastmodifiedbyid from account where id='"+tempAccId+"'");//This is my first request to fetch some data
SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(request, failBlock: { error in
            //handle your error
            }) { json in
             //handle your response for SELECT name,......
        }
```

As  GRiMe2D noted, the block may be executing in any other thread so bitter to update the UI in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
    //updateUI
})
```

Comment: how to distinguish the requests sir ?

Comment: Delegate function may be called on background thread. UI manipulation should be ran on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I"m not sure how Salesforce works, but generally if it is asynchronous call wait for the response and set your label's text after that. Put break point in viewDidload and see what is the text when you are setting.

If it is a asynchronous call you might be having some kind of call back, through delegates or through blocks, try to set your label's text once you get call back. Hope it helps.